# How can I show the key in an object in mui-datatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I tried defining it this way:

```
   {
      name: "colorList",
      label: "Color",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          {
            Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => {
              return key;
            });
          }
        },
      },
    },
```

And I will receive this error in the console.

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

If I'll `console.log(value)`, I can see the data in the console.

```
  customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
             console.log(value)
            },
```

[image]

How can I show the access they `key` and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

states, React requires children in an array to have a stable identity allowing React to identify which elements have been changed, added or removed during the component lifecycle. The identity is assigned to components with the `key` prop. The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) are very clear about this. In fact, it is recommended to use a string that is unique among all list siblings.

Assumed that the object keys, e. g. `Black` and `Gold`, are unique, you could do something along those lines to use them as component keys and also display them in the table:

```js
    {
      name: "colorList",
      label: "Color",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => {
            return <p key={key}>{key}</p>;
          });
        },
      },
    }
```